# How to Format Date Column in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel WorkSheet.I am going to populate Recordset from Sql Data using vba Macro.It works fine but I would like to know how to format Date Column as "dd/MM/yyyy" from (E5:E10).I have tried below code but date format is not working.Please advsie how to do that....

```
Private Sub CmdShowDetails_Click()

Dim ConKha As New ADODB.Connection
Dim TmpRst As New ADODB.Recordset
ConKha.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Pass@123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=GloveERP;Data Source=Arindsql"
ConKha.CommandTimeout = 600
SqlStr = "Select 'Outward' SupplyType,'Job Work' SubType,'Others' DocType,A.GatePassNo DocNo,Convert(Char(10),A.GatePassDate,103) DocDate,'K H EXPORTS INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED GLOVE DIVISION' From_OtherPartyName,'33AAACR1714R1ZA' From_GSTIN,'142/1 Trunk Road' From_Address1 ,'Perumugai' From_Address2,'Perumugai' From_Place,'632009' From_PinCode,'TAMIL NADU' From_State,"
SqlStr = SqlStr & "Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( B.CompanyName, '!', ' ' ), '#', ' ' ), '$', ' ' ), '&', ' '), '.', ' '),',',' '),';',' '),':',' '),'*',' ') "
SqlStr = SqlStr & " To_OtherPartyName,B.GSTNo TO_GST,B.Address1 + ' ' + B.Address2 To_Address1 ,B.Address3 + ' ' +  B.Address4 To_Address2,'' To_Place,'632009' To_PinCode,'Tamil Nadu' To_State,C.ItemDescriptions Product,C.Purpose [Description],C.HSNCode,D.UoMName Unit,C.Quantity, (C.Quantity * C.Rate) + ((C.Quantity * C.Rate) * (C.GSTPercentage/100))  AssesableValue,'9+9+0+0' TaxRate, 0 CGSTAmount, 0 SGSTAmount,0 IGSTAmount,0 CESSAmount,'Road' TransMode,10 Distance,"
SqlStr = SqlStr & " '' TransName,'' TransId,'' TransDocNo,Convert(Char(10),A.GatePassDate,103) TransDate,A.VehicleNo,'' ErrorList from Material_Trn_GatePassHeader A Join Common_Ref_Company B On (B.CompanyId = A.SupplierId) Join Material_Trn_GatePassDetails C On (C.GatePassHeaderId = A.GatePassHeaderId) Join Common_Ref_UoM D On (D.UoMID = C.UOMId) Where (A.GatePassNo Between '" & TxtFromGPNo.Text & "' And '" & TxtToGPNo.Text & "')"
TmpRst.Open SqlStr, ConKha, adOpenForwardOnly

Worksheets("eWayBill").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset TmpRst

Worksheets("eWayBill").Range("E4:E10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

TmpRst.Close
ConKha.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Try applying the format before populating the data.

Comment: What does the date values look like before the .numberformat? Are they left-aligned or right-aligned in the cells? Is your computer typically DMY or MDY?

Answer (score 0):

The slashes are interpreted in a special way.

Try this:

```
.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"
```

to force showing the slashes.

Comment: Thanks for quick support, I have tried above code to format but its shows an error message as "Unable to Set NumberFormat property for range class"

Comment: Is there a protection on your worksheet? Does this error occur only with the new code or also with your original code?

Comment: this is my original code      Worksheets("eWayBill").Range("E4:E10").NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"""

Comment: So my question was: has your worksheet been protected against changes? Right-click on the `eWayBill` tab in the lower left corner of your workbook and check if there is an entry `Remove protection` (or similar)

Comment: Otherwise you should google your error message. There are several hits.